# Sorting a associative array based on two keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort the id field by pushing array record with null value to bottom. If id value is present, then sort the col_1 by asc.

I have a multidimensional array like this.

```
Array
(
  [0]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>1166
          [col_1]=>9.4
        )
  [1]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>
          [col_1]=>2.4
        )
  [2]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>1012
          [col_1]=>0.96
        )
  [3]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>1856
          [col_1]=>7.47
        )
)
```

I want to sort it by id as well as col_1. 
I tried

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
  $x[$key]  = $row['id'];
  $y[$key]  = $row['col_1'];
}
array_multisort($x, SORT_DESC, $y, SORT_ASC, $arr);
```

I got the following as my result

```
Array
(
  [0]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>1856
          [col_1]=>7.47
        )
  [1]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>1166
          [col_1]=>9.4
        )
  [2]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>1012,
          [col_1]=>0.96
        )
  [3]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>
          [col_1]=>2.47
        )
)
```

But I want the result as,

```
Array
(
  [0]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>1012
          [col_1]=>0.96
        )
  [1]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>1856
          [col_1]=>7.47
        )
  [2]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>1166
          [col_1]=>9.4
        )
  [3]=> Array
        (
          [id]=>
          [col_1]=>2.4
        )
)
```

'id' field can be null also for some records. But col_1 will be there for all the records.

Comment: Your expected result is not sorted in any way that I can discern.

Comment: the expected result is sorted in asc by col_1, if the id field is not null. If the id is null then push it to bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sophisticated, but readable and straight forward:

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1166,
        'col_1' => 9.4
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'col_1' => 2.4
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1012,
        'col_1' => 0.96
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1856,
        'col_1' => 7.47
    ]
];
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a['col_1']>$b['col_1']);
});
usort($data, function($a) {
    return !isset($a['id']);
});
print_r($data);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1012
            [col_1] => 0.96
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1856
            [col_1] => 7.47
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1166
            [col_1] => 9.4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] =>
            [col_1] => 2.4
        )

)
```

---

In your comment below you now make an additional requirement. I doubt there is a direct way to evaluate *both* requirements in a straight forward sorting approach. So why not try a readable and obvious one:

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1166,
        'col_1' => 9.4
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'col_1' => 2.4
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'col_1' => 0.2
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1012,
        'col_1' => 0.96
    ],
    [
        'id' => null,
        'col_1' => 12
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1856,
        'col_1' => 7.47
    ]
];
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a['col_1']>$b['col_1']);
});
$withId = array_filter($data, function($entry) {
    return isset($entry ['id']);
});
$withoutId = array_filter($data, function($entry) {
    return !isset($entry ['id']);
});
$data = array_merge($withId, $withoutId);
print_r($data);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1012
            [col_1] => 0.96
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1856
            [col_1] => 7.47
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1166
            [col_1] => 9.4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] =>
            [col_1] => 0.2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] =>
            [col_1] => 2.4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] =>
            [col_1] => 12
        )

)
```

Comment: does $a,$b refers to my $x and $y ?

Comment: @kishram No, not really. Take a look at the documentation of the `usort()` function and you will understand their meaning: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: why sort two times?

Comment: @kishram I added a variant that probably does what you are looking for...

Comment: @bansi Because it is the approach easiest to read and follow. And because I am a lousy programmer. :-) And, actually, because you do need a two pass algorithm for this...

Comment: awesome..!! this is what i wanted exactly ..! great.

Comment: @arkascha with the changed requirements your approach seems to be most logical

Comment: Your beautiful code in [almost unreadable demo](https://eval.in/759789)

Comment: @bansi You want to demonstrate that one can get around the two additional variables? Certainly possible, but harder to read. I would consider that bad style for that reason...

Comment: @arkascha I agree, code must be easily readable and maintainable. just added the `unreadable demo` for fun sake only.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the usort function to make a custom sort.

```
 function customSort($a, $b) {
    if (null === $a['id'] && null === $b['id']) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (null === $a['id']) {
        return 1;
    } 
    if (null === $b['id']) {
        return -1;
    }
    return ($a['col_1'] < $b['col_1']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$array = [
    [
        'id' => 1012,
        'col_1' => 0.96
        ],
    [
        'id' => 1856,
        'col_1' => 7.47
        ],
            [
        'id' => null,
        'col_1' => 2.4
        ],
    [
        'id' => 1166,
        'col_1' => 9.4
        ],

    ];



    usort($array, 'customSort');
    print_r($array);
```

This returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1012
            [col_1] => 0.96
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1856
            [col_1] => 7.47
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1166
            [col_1] => 9.4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [col_1] => 2.4
        )

)
```

Which is what you expected. Hope this helped.

Comment: This works perfectly. but I have one small issue. I may have more than two records with null id. I want those records to be sorted by col_1 below this order.

Comment: simply replace `return 0;` with  `return ($a['col_1'] < $b['col_1']) ? -1 : 1;` and you should be done ;)